# Strange glitches when using "Pull to refresh"

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh, rippledrawable

When I launch my activity i refresh my list with

```
swipeContainer.setRefreshing(true);
```

after refreshing is call

```
swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
```

But during the networkcalls The refreshIcon glitches, in a fraction of a second

and If I look to the Android Monitor I get these lines

```
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7f926f5800 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f8dcf50e0

D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7f7ce78000 (ListView) with handle 0x7f89455380
```

What does this mean? and how can I fix this that I don't get the glitches and messages?

it is realy annoying

**EDIT 1**
This is how I call my setRefreshing(true)

```
    swipeContainer.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipeContainer.setRefreshing(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use handler ......

Comment: Like EDIT 1? because this is how I call the setRefreshing(true);

Comment: Why not use swipeRefresh? I use a swipeRefresh for my code, if you want i can post that.

Comment: Would it be possible that you are doing heavy tasks on the UI thread? Which could result in overall decreased UI performance in your app (even for a slight moment)

Comment: What are heavy tasks? And all my networkcalls are done in an AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>

Answer (score 0):

I use a swipeRefreshLayout, this might be usefull for you:

**My XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background2"
android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
android:weightSum="1">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:alpha="0.90"
        android:layout_weight="1.01" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**This is the code I use to refresh the activity:**

```
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipelayout);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have done as well, but the first time you open your activity the list needs to be called from my server, and if you use just Your code the progressbar only appears when you pull down, I tought by caling setRefreshing(true) the progressbar will be showen, and if the task is done (in the other thread) I call setRefreshing(false)

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren So what you are saying you want it to refresh upon loading data from your server? i am doing technically everything the same, i pull data from an WebAPI and then fill the listview with the data, if i understand your response correctly, what you are saying is you want to refresh the listview upon creating it? why? if you populate the listview correctly and have it setup correctly it should already be filled before you see anthing. If i didnt understand fully then sorry :)

Comment: No that is not true, I open my activity and only then will the data be called from the internet, because I only need that data on that activity

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren So you create your view first and then populate the list? sorry I dont fully understand your situation.

Comment: yes so my view is created then I get my list of my server, (over network) and while You are waiting for the list (over network) I want to show the user the same loading bar as if he pulled down to refresh the list

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren is there any specific reason why you want to do it like this? Instead of that you can also load the data first and then show the user, then you can use this code for example to refresh the list for any changes.

Comment: yes, but when you are loading the data first! the listview is empty so the user doesn't see anything, loading can take up to 3 seconds with bad internet. So during this loading-proces I want to show a progresbar (the same one as if the user pulled down)

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren Then im sorry but i cant help you. I only started with android 2 months ago so i dont have alot of knowledge about this subject. Goodluck and have a nice day :)